# ro root fs on /proc/mounts

Tags: mount, root, read-only, proc

my ubuntu 9.10 is mounting the root filesystem as read only.
 already tried some options found on the forums like fsck, remounts, etc, but no luck...

for what I could find, my problem is is /proc/mounts:

```
root@WKS00335:~# cat /proc/mounts
 rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
 none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
 none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
 udev /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
 /dev/mapper/WKS00355-root / ro,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
 none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
```

my root is defined as ro

for etc/fstab, I've got:

```
root@WKS00335:~# cat /etc/fstab
 # /etc/fstab: static....
 #comments#
 #<file system>...
 proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
 /dev/mapper/WKS00355-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
 #boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
 UUID=9254b90c-c665-4dc1-8e1a-7b2e6a493ca4 /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
 /dev/mapper/WKS00355-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
 /dev/sdc0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
 /dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

the question is, how can I change /proc/mounts so that /dev/mapper/WKS00355-root / is rw instead of ro?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo grep -ir WKS00355-root /var/log/ ; dmesg | grep WKS00355-root`

It would certainly appear that SOME kind of error is causing your root partition to go read-only, so you'll need to look through the logfiles to try to figure out why.  The above command should return something relevant.

If it doesn't, the error in question might be in a logfile that's already been compressed and archived.  Easiest thing to do, if uptime isn't an issue, is just to reboot and then immediately issue the command above if root is still read-only.

What happens if you issue the command `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` ?